# lodash: Filter collection using array of values

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I found this solution:

```
var collections = [
    {name: 'somename1',  desctiption: 'xyz'}, 
    {name: 'somename',   desctiption: 'ds'},
    {name: 'somename',   desctiption: 'rtrt'},
    {name: 'somename2',  desctiption: 'nhf'},
    {name: 'somename1',  desctiption: 'qwe'}
];

names = ['somename1', 'somename2']

_(collections)
    .keyBy('name')
    .at(names)
    .value();
```

But the result contains only one value with **somename1**, how can I get all values with **somename1**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If by all values you mean the objects, then

```
const values = collections.filter(e => ['somename1', 'somename2'].includes(e.name))
```

If you mean the description, then

```
const descriptions = values.map(e => e.description)
```

For this kind of stuff you don't really need lodash anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find method to get one value

```
_.find(collections,{name : 'somename1'})
```

For all objects with somename1

```
_.pullAllWith(collections,{ name : 'somename1'})
```

Console.log the results are as expected

Comment: I need find by an array of values: names = ['somename1', 'somename2']